# Sum duplicate's values when using LOAD FILE

Tags: mysql, duplicates, load-data-infile, sql-insert

I have a table:

```
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| abc |   4 |
| def |   1 |
| ghi |   2 |
```

`foo` has unique index.
I want to load a file into this table summing `bar` values of duplicates by `foo` column:

```
abc \t 7
ghi \t 3
jkl \t 4
```

Is there any way to **sum** values in duplicate rows during `LOAD DATA`?
This command **replaces** old values in a row:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' REPLACE
INTO TABLE `table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' (`foo`,`bar`);
```

I want to have a table like this:

```
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| abc |  11 |
| def |   1 |
| ghi |   5 |
| jkl |   4 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve what you want since the source of the records are from a file and not from a table. Follow this steps to insert new row or update existing row.

- create a temporary table which serves as a temporary target table for the records.
- load the records into the temporary table assuming the new table is named `TempTable` and has two columns: `foo`, and `bar`

table creation ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
    foo VARCHAR(30),
    bar INT
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE TempTable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' (`foo`,`bar`);
```

- after the records has been loaded, let's start with the combining of records. MySQL has implemented a feature called `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, which basically inserts a new records but if the record conflicts with the existing key, it then updates the record. A `key` should be define first but in your case, you can directly execute the statement since you have mentioned that `foo` is already unique.

using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` you can combine `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`,

```
INSERT INTO YourExistingTable (Foo, Bar) 
SELECT Foo, Bar
FROM   TempTable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Bar = VALUES(Bar) + Bar;
```

- the records will be combined after you have executed the statement. You can now drop the temporary table.

dropping temporary table,

```
DROP TABLE TempTable
```